# Firebase Messaging iOS - On first run of the app 1 of the multiple topic subscription fails

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have just added the latest ios Firebase SDK[5.0.1] to the app.
Seeing a problem on first run of the app after install.

After receiving the fcmToken in

```
-(void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken
```

I loop through and subscribe to multiple topics. Consistently only one of them fails whilst the others succeed. The error message is

> Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=501 "(null)"

I can send messages from the Notification Composer to the topics that succeeded but messages to the topic that failed do not get to the device.
I also tried subscribing to the topics after I receive the APNS token instead. Still the same problem

If I run the app again all of the topics register without error.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Where are you subscribing for topic?

Comment: in didReceiveRegistrationToken - when I get the firebase token callback